# How can I use repository pattern in Entity Framework Navigation-Properties?

Tags: entity-framework

Suppose we have two Entities Person and Address and therefore two Repositories:

```
public class PersonRepository {
    Person FindById(object id){...}
    void Insert(Person entity){...}
    .....
}
```

And

```
public class AddressRepository {
    Address FindById(object id){...}
    void Insert(Address entity){...}
    .....
}
```

Any user of the PersonRepository can access the Addresses of the Person throw the navigation property and manipulate it without using AdressRepository:

personRepository.FindById(100).Addresses.Add(new Address());

is this behavior allowed?

And in general how to handle the Navigation-Properties in the Repository Pattern?

Thanks

Comment: You can do away with the navigation properties, and I think a repository pattern purist would advocate that or a similar approach, but honestly doing that can make your API more awkward to use. I don't really see an issue w/ what you're doing here.

Comment: It is not about me. But if you provide public properties you can't control who will access them. I don't know how can I restrict this kind of access.

Comment: There are a lot of different ways you can shape the code that consumes your API. You can obviously change the API itself, but that's not 100% effective (even if you remove a nav property a developer can still set the ID directly). Or, you can create and enforce coding standard rules with StyleCop and/or FxCop if your API is being used internally by your team.